# In a Load Balancing scenario do you need to use ChannelFactory to create a channel or can you just Open the connection?

Tags: wcf, load-balancing

If for example you have a WCF service that is deployed in 2 machines and sits behind a load balancer, do you need to create a channel, using ChannelFactory.CreateChannel(), in order to call it or can you just Open() the connection without creating the channel?
I understand that creating the channel and reusing it is the best approach since creating the channel is an expensive operation. But in this case I just want to know if just with Open() it should still work fine without problems

*I know that there's a lot of factors that can affect this: like binding type, behavior, load balancer configuration, network, etc. So I'm sorry if this question is too generic and in that case please feel free to close it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, caller affinity will be maintained with one load-balanced service instance if you re-use a channel and you have a load balancer which supports sticky sessions. Closing and then re-creating the channel causes any affinity to reset.

If you don't want this behaviour and you're using basicHttpBinding / webHttpBinding then if you disable HTTP keep alive on the binding then calls made over the same channel will be load-balanced. This is only available on basicHttpBinding or webHttpBinding since these are the only bindings which do not require a transport session and are fully stateless.

It's worth mentioning that if you don't configure sticky sessions on your load balancer, or you disable keep-alive on wsHttp or wsDualHttp bindings, then you will get errors as the transport session may not be maintained against one host, i.e. you will actually get load balanced behaviour over the same channel, which will break these bindings. This is also the case for netTCP, which is also stateful. It's possible that if you turn off the security on the wsHttp binding that it falls back to being stateless since it's the security requirement which enforces the transport session, but I don't know.

Sources:

- http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/load-balancing-and-scaling-your-wcf-services
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273122(v=vs.100).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I'll have a look at the links you provided